# SVG Image flash in Safari when moving nodes

Tags: image, svg, safari

In Safari 11, when I re-append an (already loaded) Image node to a SVG there is a noticeable flash as the image is reloaded. Safari does another network request for the image and, I guess, technically obeying that the image has no cache-control but this does not happen in Chrome or Firefox...

```
document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(document.getElementById("img"));
```

The issue can be seen here: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxOXPQ

Are there any tricks to prevent this behavior?

thanks,
Mitch